# Creating MySQL table for user-input text strings

Tags: php, mysql

Using a PHP form to insert the text strings from users into the table, and another form to pull it later on another page, what would be the best method of creating a table in MySQL for strings of text, and what options when creating the table would likely be necessary to best handle text strings?

The complicating factor, I suppose, is that the text that would exist in the table doesn't exist yet (as it would need to be input through the form, etc.), I am unsure if this is why I've had trouble (along with my relative inexperience, so I am unsure of what, precisely would be an ideal table configuration).

Since I don't want to store any other data beyond this user input (like I said, just strings of text i.e a sentence), I assumed I only needed one column when creating the table, but I was unsure of this as well; it seems it is possible I am more likely just overlooking something about how SQL works.

Comment: (1) you have to consider the estimated, maximum length of such strings to decide whether to use varchar-fields or text-fields in mysql.  
(2) consider having a 2nd field called id (int, primary key, auto increment), when you need to reference those strings later. (3) use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql, which is deprecated.

Comment: You'll need to create a database, a user, and a table, and your fields (like michi said, a unique identifier is a good idea). Check out PDO (or mysqli). Easier to work and since you're learning, might as well start with what's current.

Comment: @michi Thank you, would the length of the strings (for example, a human-readable sentence of text) lend itself to varchar vs. text-fields?

Comment: 1) Do not suppress errors using `@`. Use `error_reporting`. 2) Stop using `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated. 3) Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates for "key's" data, than you can use this SQL query: "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value_field_name=?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put my comments into an answer now:

1. consider the estimated, maximum length of such strings to decide whether to use `varchar`-fields or `text`-fields in mysql.

   Quoting from the MySQL-Manual (BTW a good read for your purpose):
   Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

   It is said that `varchar`is faster, for a **good summary**, see [MySQL: Large VARCHAR vs. TEXT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text)
2. consider having at least a 2nd field called id (int, primary key, auto increment), when you need to reference those strings later. Consider having a field referencing the author of that string. Maybe a field to store the date and time when the string was put into the database would be a good idea as well.
3. use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql, which is deprecated.
   See here, there are links to good tutorials in the 1st answer: [How do I migrate my site from mysql to mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598854/how-do-i-migrate-my-site-from-mysql-to-mysqli)

Comment: Thank you,, sections 1 and 2 were exactly what I needed. I was unaware of the differences in mysqli, PDO, etc. so I am going to update that as well.

Comment: @josephmarhee glad I could help, have fun!