# delete contents of a column in a table using button

Tags: php

I have a table named "users" in my database. My table has 2 columns, "user_id" and "profile". user_id keeps the id of the user that is currently logged in. The profile keeps the url of image that the user has uploaded in his profile page. All I want is to create a button that will delete the contents of profile column for the user that is logged in. Any idea how to move on?

```
<?php                       
function deleteimage($user_id){
$sql="DELETE `profile` FROM `users`  WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id;";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Error when trying to delete...");
}
?>

<input type="button" value="Delete">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set up the connection to your database first.

I have three files, the main PHP script like yours, a db_config file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_SERVER", "%address%");
define("DB_USER", "%username%");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "%password%");
define("DB_DATABASE", "%dbname%");
?>
```

Then a connect utility script:

```
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

Then you can use this in your main script to open the connection:

```
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
```

at the beginning to open the connection to your database.  You can then do a query as you did in your question above.  This format makes it nice and easy to have queries going from multiple PHP scripts as the connector a separate class.

You can then do the logic for executing that SQL query when the button is clicked

For removing the image URL you want something like

```
UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = NULL WHERE `user_id` = $user_id
```

You can't directly access the button click as it were. The PHP is just telling the client page to display a button. If you want to receieve when it was clicked you need to use something like a POST self-referral like below to make a button which when clicked sends a signal back to the server page:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

Then, at the top of your PHP page you can do

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    deleteimage($user_id);
}
```

To run the function to do the URL delete function only once the button is clicked.

To migrate your script to MYSQLI for future compatibility, take a look at the oracle wiki guide [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi).

It has a tool which you point at your PHP scripts and it will make the changes for you.  Took me about 2 mins to convert all my scripts

Hope this is helpful

Comment: I have try it, looks great until now, any idea how to make the button to call UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = NULL WHERE `user_id` = $user_id

Comment: I put them in the following order: 1.function deleteimage 2.if(isset($_POST['submit'])) and 3. the form. The problem now is that I get the message Undefined variable: user_id. Is there a problem in the order I used?

Comment: You should not be using the `mysql_` functions in PHP anymore. This isn't the best advice I'm afraid...

Comment: I agree, however, depending on the stage of script development, it may be easier (and I am) getting mysql functional as it is what I know, then migrate to mysqli as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598854/how-do-i-migrate-my-site-from-mysql-to-mysqli

Comment: @Stefanos $user_id is a a placeholder which you have to assign a value to before you can use. Use PHP sessions or a post or get variable to get the user_id which you want to have the profile URL removed from

Answer (score 1):

The `DELETE` keyword is for rows not columns

If you want to empty a column you would `UPDATE` the record

```
"UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = NULL  WHERE `user_id` = $user_id;"
```

Or, if you `profile` column does not accept NULL values

```
"UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = ''  WHERE `user_id` = $user_id;"
```

However, you should be using `mysqli_` or `PDO` as the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and being removed from PHP

Also, please ensure you are escaping the `$user_id` variable you are passing into this method otherwise you could be leaving yourself open to SQL injection vulnerabilities

Comment: or '' instead of NULL if the column is set as NOT NULL

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make column emply you can also set blank value or Null value

```
UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = '' WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id;
```

or

```
UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = NULL  WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id;
```

Comment: You need to put backticks around the `user_id` column in the where clause. At the moment its a string which would cause a SQL error.  Just a heads up.

Comment: i just paste from php my admin with static and change variable sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You have to set 1 global variable which will contain user_id of logged in user.

And on button click you can call a PHP with GET or POST with this user_id(global variable) value as a parameter .

It should work.