# How to supplement or update deprecated `mysql_real_escape_string`

Tags: php, forms, security

I'm a PHP novice, trying to validate HTML form submission via PHP learned in a tutorial.

Code uses `mysql_real_escape_string` which PHP.net [says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is deprecated.

Here's an excerpt of that entire section:

```
/*Cleans an array to protect against injection attacks.*/
function f_clean($array) {
    return array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array);
}
```

What, if anything, should I add or change in the PHP in order maintain this security measure?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, but I agree what I'm asking about is part of at least one answer at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). That said, the answers there get so lengthy and complicated (for a novice like me, anyway), they're a bit unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

The updated non-deprecated equivalent of `mysql_real_escape_string` is `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

However, `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not infallible! Even though in most *practical* cases by the average use, you should take precaution and use it in combination with `trim()`, parameterized inserts, prepared statements, and strict inputs. There are many questions and resources to help you on this.

Comment: That's it? I just now confirmed I have have mysql Server version: 5.5.42-cll-lve and Current PHP version: 5.4.432.0 with **PHP extension: mysqli**, so I guess that'll do fine. Thank you!

Comment: I just added the i after mysql, as directed, and upon submitting, the form now returns this error: `Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(ID), timestamp int NOT NU' at line 1`

Comment: To follow-up, I removed the `i` and the form submission is working fine again. I'm certainly not an expert, but switching from mysql to mysqli is a somewhat involved process: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598854/how-do-i-migrate-my-site-from-mysql-to-mysqli)

Comment: Your sql syntax is probably wrong then, what is the statement you are escaping?

Comment: Here it is:  `/*Cleans an array to protect against injection attacks.*/
function f_clean($array) {
    return array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array);
}` Thank you.

Comment: `function return($x) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($x);

}
array_map('return', $array);`

Comment: Hmm. Thank you @Valkyrie, but I don't know whether I'm making progress or falling farther behind. If the function `f_clean` is removed, per your suggested code immediately above, won't other instances where `f_clean` is used, such as `/*This cleans our &_POST array to prevent against SQL injection attacks.*/
 $_POST = f_clean($_POST);`  become problematic?