# Checking value if already exist not working (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I working on how to check if value already exist in a database.
Whenever I try to input something *(Example: 000)* there's always an error: **Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource...**,
but the input was saved in the database

then if I input the same again, the condition to check if value exist doesn't work

```
if (isset($_POST['add']))
    {
        $docid = $_POST['docid'];

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT doc.docid, doc_details.docid FROM doc, doc_details WHERE docid='$docid'");
        $number_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);
        if ($number_of_rows > 0)
            {
                echo "<script> alert('Your input already exist, no input made'); </script>";
            }
        else
            {
                $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO doc (docid) VALUES ('$docid')");
                $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO doc_details (docid) VALUES ('$docid')");
                echo "<script> alert('ADDING: Successful'); </script>";
            }
    }
```

Comment: post your $check function

Comment: echo mysql_num_rows($check); It will display count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [described in the manual](http://php.net/mysql_query) mysql_query returns `false` when an error occurs. As the error says, `$check` is not a resource, so it's probably `false`. So there is an error in your first `SELECT` query, you should debug that.

You could try this, it'll probably tell you what's wrong:

```
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT doc.docid, doc_details.docid FROM doc, doc_details WHERE docid='$docid'");
    if (false === $check)
      var_dump(mysql_error());
```

Since [false is never bigger than 0](https://3v4l.org/469pi), your script will always attempt to insert, ignoring the error.

Offtopic; you should [migrate to mysqli_*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598854/how-do-i-migrate-my-site-from-mysql-to-mysqli) instead of using mysql_ functions.

Comment: it says, string(43) "Column 'docid' in where clause is ambiguous",
how do I solve that?

Comment: Simplest solution is to check only the doc table:  `$check = mysql_query("SELECT docid FROM doc WHERE docid='$docid'");`